# Allow numbers in 6th and 7th position of regex

Tags: regex

I have this Regex:

```
^[A-Za-z]{1,6}[0,9]{6,7}[A-Za-z\d]{7,14}
```

The string that has to be uses in the regex is this:

```
Addfk12dkdkdk
```

The first four characters must be a char then after that there should only be allowed 2 numbers and after the two numbers any char and any number is allowed.

Comment: `[0,9]` is saying it can be the characters 0 , or 9.  `{1,6}` does not say characters 1-6, it says it can be between 1 and 6 characters long.  This works on the first part, but the `{6,7}` says it can be 6 or 7 characters of 0 , or 9. Like "a000000AAAAAAA" would match your regex.

Comment: Is `[0,9]` a typo for `[0-9]`? Why not just use `\d` like you did later?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't understand what you actually want because your regex looks like it wants 6 alpha characters first, or up to 6?  But you describe it as the first 4 characters must be a char, and your example has 5.

Answer (score 1):

> The first four characters must be a char then after that there should only be allowed 2 numbers and after the two numbers any char and any number is allowed

- first four characters must be a char: `[a-zA-Z]{4}`

  - `[a-zA-Z]` any character
  - `{4}` repeated 4 times
- there should only be allowed 2 numbers: `\d{2}`

  - `\d` - any digit (equivalent of `[0-9]`)
  - `{2}` - repeated 2 times
- any char and any number is allowed: `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`

  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - will match any character or number
  - * - repeated 0 or more times, you didn't specify the limits of repetition, so I've assumed that it will be ok. If you want to have different amounts of repetitions you can use other quantifiers: `+` - for one or more repetition, `{n,m}` - from `n` to `m` repetitions.

Everything together: `[a-zA-Z]{4}\d{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]*`

You can test your regexes here: https://regex101.com/